# Getting the occurences of a date in a specific week

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I would like to get the occurences of a day in a specific week (the week that includes `today`). I have an array of `visits` with a specified `location` and `date` that I want to transform.

```js
const today = new Date(Date.parse("2021-05-13")); // set today
const numDay = today.getDate();

const twoDaysAgo = new Date(); 
twoDaysAgo.setDate(numDay - 2); // set 2 days ago from today

const twelveDaysAgo = new Date(); 
twelveDaysAgo.setDate(numDay - 12); // set 12 days ago from today

const visits = [{
    location: "Paris",
    date: today
  },
  {
    location: "Berlin",
    date: twoDaysAgo
  },
  {
    location: "Brussels",
    date: twoDaysAgo
  },
  {
    location: "Rome",
    date: twelveDaysAgo
  }
];
```

I would like to process the data so that the number of times a day occurs in the specific week can be tracked as a number and the locations are stored in an array. If there are no visits for a certain day, they do not need to be stored and it should just say `numVisits: 0`.

This is the outcome I would like to achieve.

```js
const thisWeekResult = [{
  monday: {
    numVisits: 0
  },
  tuesday: {
    numVisits: 2,
    locations: ["Berlin", "Brussels"]
  },
  wednesday: {
    numVisits: 0,
  },
  thursday: {
    numVisits: 1,
    locations: ["Paris"]
  },
  friday: {
    numVisits: 0,
  },
  saturday: {
    numVisits: 0,
  },
  sunday: {
    numVisits: 0,
  }
}];
```

Comment: Today is thursday, is that fri/sat/sun _last week_ or _this week_ (ie, tomorrow, saturday, sunday - there cant be visits in the future)

Comment: From monday until `today`, days after `today` should normally not occur so should also have `numVisits: 0`, I should have made that clear excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the beginning of the week (`start` in the code below being sunday just gone).

Then you `reduce` the 7 days beyond that date, and look for records on that dat from the original set using `filter`. Finally you just build up the object required for each day

```js
const today = new Date(Date.parse("2021-05-13")); // set today
const numDay = today.getDate();

const twoDaysAgo = new Date(); 
twoDaysAgo.setDate(numDay - 2); // set 2 days ago from today
const twelveDaysAgo = new Date(); 
twelveDaysAgo.setDate(numDay - 12); // set 12 days ago from today

const visits = [{
    location: "Paris",
    date: today
  },
  {
    location: "Berlin",
    date: twoDaysAgo
  },
  {
    location: "Brussels",
    date: twoDaysAgo
  },
  {
    location: "Rome",
    date: twelveDaysAgo
  }
];

const start = new Date()
start.setDate(today.getDate() - today.getDay())

const result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].reduce( (acc,d) => {
   const date = new Date()
   date.setDate(start.getDate() + d);
  
   const day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {weekday:'long'}).format(date).toLowerCase();
   const records = visits.filter(v => v.date.getYear() == date.getYear() && v.date.getMonth() == date.getMonth() && v.date.getDate() == date.getDate());
   acc[day] = records.length
    ? {
         numVisits: records.length,
         locations: records.map(r => r.location)
     }
    : {numVisits: 0 };
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow! That is one beautiful piece of code, thank you!